# Rails Console results in PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

In Prodcution when i try to access the `rails c` and run any command on the Database i am getting the following error

```
2.3.1 :001 > Campaign.all
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
... 22 levels...
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/rails/skreem-ror/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I have set the Passwords in the environment variables. Any solution on how to change it?

```
rails@skreem-production:~/skreem-ror$ rails c production
Running via Spring preloader in process 6158
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.5.2)
2.3.1 :001 > Rails.env
 => "production"
2.3.1 :002 > Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
 => {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"rails", "password"=>nil, "database"=>"skreem_production"}
2.3.1 :003 >
```

Comment: did you check database.yml specify the username and password for the production environment?

Comment: also for production you can try "rails console production" instead of rails c

Comment: yes it is set. in database.yml.

Comment: @power that is not working as well

Comment: if this error appear, I am thinking it also have to come when you try to create db by using rake db:create. what you think?

Comment: @power unfortunately no :( the app is working fine

Comment: On that same console, what do you get, when you run the following:

`Rails.env` 

and

`Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]`

Comment: @Swanand i think the password being passed is nill http://pastebin.com/cwZ9kbJN

Comment: @Swanand interestingly if i try to out put the ENV environment its being displayed

Comment: In that case, `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` might have been set, try printing that out.

Comment: Also, password being nil clearly indicates either of the three things:

1. Password is not set in `database.yml`
2. If an ENV var is being used for password, that ENV var is not set
3. The `DATABASE_URL` env var is set.

Comment: @Swanand 2.3.1 :001 > ENV["DATABASE_URL"]
 => nil

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. the only possible and easiest solution i found is just close the current tab and open the rails console in new fresh tab.